# foreach if no objects start with value

Tags: powershell

Right now the below works.  What I do want though is if it loops through all the `$a` values and none of them starts with sending to then send out a separate alert.

```
Import-Module JAMS
$MyEntry = Get-JAMSEntry -Entry <<JAMS_NOTIFY_JAMS_ENTRY>>
$FQDN=(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).DNSHostName+"."+(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Domain
Set-Location -Path "C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent"
foreach ($a in $MyEntry.AuditTrail) {
    Write-Host $a.Message
    if ($a.Message.StartsWith("Sending")) {
        $Status = "0"
        Write-Host "Sending Data to Zabbix Item"
        Write-Host "Server: " $FQDN
        Write-Host "Status: " $Status
        .\zabbix_sender.exe -vv -c "C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\zabbix_agentd.conf" -s $FQDN -k app.jams.server.email -o $Status
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement correctly; this is probably the easiest/cleanest way:

```
$sendingMessages = $MyEntry.AuditTrail | Where-Object Message -Like "Sending*"

if (-not $sendingMessages) {
    Write-Output "No messages starting with 'Sending'."
}
else {
    foreach ($sendingMessage in $sendingMessages) {
        Write-Output $sendingMessage
    }
}
```